# Visual Studio C#: dotnet run Couldn't find project to run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Hi I'm new to programming and am trying to run a C# project in Visual Studio 2019. The project runs fine when I press the run button at the top of the window but the issue is I need it to run using `dotnet run` but I get the error `Couldn't find project to run. Ensure a project exists in C:\directories`

I have to get it to run this way because I am trying to create a program that can take user input. Currently I'm watching a tutorial series so I am trying to use `Console.Readline();`

I can provide more information if necessary, I am new to programming and am not exactly sure what information someone may need to help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your code in C:\Directories, or a sub-directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Please make sure your project is .NET Core 2.x or later versions.
[image: here]
2.Discover the storage location of ConsoleApp1.csproj.

(Your project storage location is
C:\Users\path\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1)

According to your description, I built a similar project. The execution process is as follows:
[image: here]

Comment: Hi, thanks to you I believe I am in the right path in my directory but my program still won't run using `dotnet run` I'm new to posting on here. Is there anyway I can reply with a screenshot so I can show you what I'm doing. I'm sure its just a dumb mistake.

Comment: There may be some problems that we have overlooked. I would appreciate it if you could show your complete storage path and demonstrate the process of executing commands.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to run this project from the **Developer Powershell** using `dotnet run`. Currently the path I am in is `C:\Users\path\source\repos\ConsoleApp1` In my directory when I go into this path there are two things. A folder under the name **ConsleApp1** and file **ConsoleApp1.sln** Sorry for my late replies, between work and school I have very little time to check the forum. I appreciate the help and let me know any other information that could help.

Comment: I have known the exact location of your project. I updated the answer, you can follow my steps.

Comment: I hope you get everything you want in life nothing has ever felt better than getting this program to run. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dotnet run "C:\path\to\my.csproj"` where you replace the path with the actual path to your project file.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to you project folder, create the project: `dotnet new console`
It will create `.csproj` file and others.
Then just run `dotnet run`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `dotnet run` in the directory of the application? Do `cd C:\path\` then `dotnet run "test.exe"`. Or just do `dotnet run "C:\path\test.exe"`. Obviously change `C:\path` to your actual path.